# Can't show json in angular

Tags: angularjs

```
  body: Object
    und: Array[1]
    0: Object
    format: "full_html"
    safe_summary: ""
    safe_value: "<p dir="rtl" style="text-align: justify;">اگر  دوست دارید قدرت <a href="http://30zin.com/content/%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA">دویدنتان</a> زیاد شود و بیشتر بدوید  و آسیب های ناشی از دویدن را هم نداشه باشید  توصیه های زیر را بخوانید تا موفقیت خوبی هنگام دویدن نصیبتان شود.<br /><strong>1- هر روز بدوید</strong><br />تداوم، کلید موفقیت در برنامه است. اگر هر روز بدوید، توانایی بدن برای سوزاندن چربی هم بیشتر می شود.<br /><br /><strong>2- لباس مناسب برای دویدن بپوشید</strong><br />بلوز،‌ شلوار و کفش ورزشی مناسب برای دویدن بپوشید. این کار هم بدن شما را در بهترین فرم و حالت نگه می دارد و هم انگیزه بخش بوده و یک وسیله تشویقی برای دویدن محسوب می شود.<br /><br /><strong>3- انعطاف پذیری خودتون را افزایش بدهید</strong><br />از تجهیزات ورزشی مناسب برای افزایش انعطاف پذیری بدن استفاده کنید تا در زمان دویدن، توانایی و ظرفیت بیشتری داشته باشید. مثلاً می توانید سه جلسه در هفته از بالش پیلاتس استفاده کنید. استفاده از این وسیله، احتمال جراحت هنگام دویدن را کمتر کرده و اثرات مفیدتری نسبت به حرکات کششی ایستا دارد<br /> <br /><strong>4- برای دویدن دلیل داشته باشید</strong><br />به یاد داشته باشید که شما از فرصت فوق العاده ای در زندگی بهرمند هستید که شاید خیلی از افراد دیگر، این فرصت رو نداشته باشند و به هر دلیلی نتوانند بدوند. این یک دلیل فوق العاده مهم و ارزشمند است. این فرصت را که به طور طبیعی در اختیار شما قرار داده شده است، هدر ندهید.<br /><br /><strong>5- هنگام<a href="http://30zin.com/content/%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA"> دویدن</a> لباس های خیلی گرم یا زیاد نپوشید</strong><br />همیشه طوری لباس بپوشید که انگار دمای محیط چند درجه گرم تر از میزان واقعی آن است. چون وقتی که شروع به دویدن می کنید،‌ بدن به طور خود به خود گرم می شود و اگر لباس زیادی پوشیده باشید،‌ احساس گرمای طاقت فرسایی خواهید کرد.<br />هرچه انعطاف بدن بیشتر باشد احتمال جراحت هنگام دویدن کمتر است<br /><br /><strong>6- با دونده های دیگر خودتان را مقایسه نکنید</strong><br />خودتان را با خودتان مقایسه کنید نه با بقیه دونده ها. مسلماً همیشه فرد یا افرادی وجود دارند که از شما سریع تر می دوند و ورزشکار تر به نظر می رسند. بر روی پیشرفت خودتان تمرکز کنید و افکار منفی و دلسرد کننده را از خودتان دور کنید.<br /><br /><strong>7- برای <a href="http://30zin.com/content/%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA">دویدن</a> از سطوح شیب دار استفاده نکنید</strong><br />هیچ وقت در سراشیب تپه ها ندوید. نیروی بسیار شدید که با دویدن در سراشیب به زانو ها وارد می شود، برای زانوها مضر است.<br /><br /><strong>8- هر روز به خودتان فشار نیاورید</strong><br />برای تقویت بدن،‌ باید به آن فرصت بدهید تا به بازسازی خود بپردازد. پس نباید هر روز با شدت خیلی زیاد ورزش کنید. بعضی از روزهای هفته به ورزش با شدت کمتر بپردازید.<br /><br /><strong>9- به صورت گروهی بدوید</strong><br />دویدن حتی به صورت انفرادی هم لذتبخش است اما اگر فرد اجتماعی هستید و دوستانی دارید که به شما انگیزه می دهند، بهتر است که با هم به دویدن بپردازید.<br /><br /><strong>10- هنگام<a href="http://30zin.com/content/%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA"> دویدن </a>یک هدف مشخص تعیین کنید</strong><br />مثلاً با خودتان قرار بگذارید که یک ربع بدوید یا مثلاً چهار کیلومتر بدوید. سعی کنید که به هدفی که تعیین کرده اید،‌ برسید.</p>↵"
    summary: ""
    value: "<p dir="rtl" style="text-align: justify;">اگر&nbsp; دوست دارید قدرت <a href="http://30zin.com/content/%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA">دویدنتان</a> زیاد شود و بیشتر بدوید&nbsp; و آسیب های ناشی از دویدن را هم نداشه باشید&nbsp; توصیه های زیر را بخوانید تا موفقیت خوبی هنگام دویدن نصیبتان شود.<br><strong>1- هر روز بدوید</strong><br>تداوم، کلید موفقیت در برنامه است. اگر هر روز بدوید، توانایی بدن برای سوزاندن چربی هم بیشتر می شود.<br><br><strong>2- لباس مناسب برای دویدن بپوشید</strong><br>بلوز،‌ شلوار و کفش ورزشی مناسب برای دویدن بپوشید. این کار هم بدن شما را در بهترین فرم و حالت نگه می دارد و هم انگیزه بخش بوده و یک وسیله تشویقی برای دویدن محسوب می شود.<br><br><strong>3- انعطاف پذیری خودتون را افزایش بدهید</strong><br>از تجهیزات ورزشی مناسب برای افزایش انعطاف پذیری بدن استفاده کنید تا در زمان دویدن، توانایی و ظرفیت بیشتری داشته باشید. مثلاً می توانید سه جلسه در هفته از بالش پیلاتس استفاده کنید. استفاده از این وسیله، احتمال جراحت هنگام دویدن را کمتر کرده و اثرات مفیدتری نسبت به حرکات کششی ایستا دارد<br>&nbsp;<br><strong>4- برای دویدن دلیل داشته باشید</strong><br>به یاد داشته باشید که شما از فرصت فوق العاده ای در زندگی بهرمند هستید که شاید خیلی از افراد دیگر، این فرصت رو نداشته باشند و به هر دلیلی نتوانند بدوند. این یک دلیل فوق العاده مهم و ارزشمند است. این فرصت را که به طور طبیعی در اختیار شما قرار داده شده است، هدر ندهید.<br><br><strong>5- هنگام<a href="http://30zin.com/content/%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA"> دویدن</a> لباس های خیلی گرم یا زیاد نپوشید</strong><br>همیشه طوری لباس بپوشید که انگار دمای محیط چند درجه گرم تر از میزان واقعی آن است. چون وقتی که شروع به دویدن می کنید،‌ بدن به طور خود به خود گرم می شود و اگر لباس زیادی پوشیده باشید،‌ احساس گرمای طاقت فرسایی خواهید کرد.<br>هرچه انعطاف بدن بیشتر باشد احتمال جراحت هنگام دویدن کمتر است<br><br><strong>6- با دونده های دیگر خودتان را مقایسه نکنید</strong><br>خودتان را با خودتان مقایسه کنید نه با بقیه دونده ها. مسلماً همیشه فرد یا افرادی وجود دارند که از شما سریع تر می دوند و ورزشکار تر به نظر می رسند. بر روی پیشرفت خودتان تمرکز کنید و افکار منفی و دلسرد کننده را از خودتان دور کنید.<br><br><strong>7- برای <a href="http://30zin.com/content/%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA">دویدن</a> از سطوح شیب دار استفاده نکنید</strong><br>هیچ وقت در سراشیب تپه ها ندوید. نیروی بسیار شدید که با دویدن در سراشیب به زانو ها وارد می شود، برای زانوها مضر است.<br><br><strong>8- هر روز به خودتان فشار نیاورید</strong><br>برای تقویت بدن،‌ باید به آن فرصت بدهید تا به بازسازی خود بپردازد. پس نباید هر روز با شدت خیلی زیاد ورزش کنید. بعضی از روزهای هفته به ورزش با شدت کمتر بپردازید.<br><br><strong>9- به صورت گروهی بدوید</strong><br>دویدن حتی به صورت انفرادی هم لذتبخش است اما اگر فرد اجتماعی هستید و دوستانی دارید که به شما انگیزه می دهند، بهتر است که با هم به دویدن بپردازید.<br><br><strong>10- هنگام<a href="http://30zin.com/content/%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA"> دویدن </a>یک هدف مشخص تعیین کنید</strong><br>مثلاً با خودتان قرار بگذارید که یک ربع بدوید یا مثلاً چهار کیلومتر بدوید. سعی کنید که به هدفی که تعیین کرده اید،‌ برسید.</p>"

        changed: "1440225054"
        cid: "0"
        comment: "2"
        comment_count: "0"
        created: "1440225054"
        data: "b:0;"
        field_external_link: Array[0]
        field_image: Object
        field_main_category_field: Object
        field_show_slideshow: Object  
        title_original: "10 نکته برای بهتر دویدن"
```

This is my json from console that i copy here . This json is comming from **Drupal** that i want to show some data in ng-repeat .

when i add this to my html :

```
 <div ng-repeat="data in innerData">
        {{data.title_original}}

    </div>
```

Comment: There is no property `title_original` shown in the data so why would this work in the view? Please provide proper problem descriptions ... `can't show json` doesn't tell us very much and provides no information about troubleshooting you have tried

Comment: sry i updated my json , please see it

Comment: Where do you add the data to the $scope?

Comment: thanks, i handle it in differnt way

Comment: we could use the code you wrote to add the date to $scope as @Fissio said to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `data` is the variable holding the json. If that's true, I don't see any field `title_original` in it. Therefor, your code won't output anything.

Also, I see your json has some html in it. If you're sure the code is safe and can't inject unwanted tags (such as `<script></script>`), you should use the directive ng-bind-html to show that content and actually interpret it as HTML. This uses the `sanitize` module from angular.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml